# INNER JOIN for two columns of the same foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose that we have two tables:

TABLE TA

```
AID BID1 BID2
--  ---- ----
01  01   02
02  01   03
03  02   01
```

TABLE TB

```
BID Name
--- ----
01  FOO
02  BOO
03  LOO
```

If I want to return the following:

```
AID Name1
--  -----
01  FOO
02  FOO
03  BOO
```

I write the following:

```
SELECT TA.AID, TB.Name as Name1 
FROM TB 
INNER JOIN TA on TB.BID = TA.BID1
```

However, I cannot figure out how to return the TB.Name that correspond to both the BID1 and BID2. More specifically I want to return the following:

```
AID Name1 Name2
--  ----- -----
01  FOO   BOO
02  FOO   LOO
03  BOO   FOO
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could join multiple times:

```
SELECT TA.AID, tb1.Name AS Name1, tb2.Name AS Name2
FROM TA
LEFT JOIN TB tb1
  ON TA.BID1 = tb1.BID
LEFT JOIN TB tb2
  ON TA.BID2 = tb2.BID;
```

Note: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will ensure you always get all records from `TA` even if there is no match.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/LMX72793)**</kbd>

Comment: Nice answer, +1 for `left outer join`

Answer (score 5):

Just use one more join

```
SELECT TA.AID, TB.Name as Name1, T1.Name as Name2
FROM TB 
INNER JOIN TA on TB.BID=TA.BID1
INNER JOIN TB T1 on T1.BID=TA.BID2;
```

Answer (score 3):

--one more way using cross apply

```
  select ta.aid,a1.*,a2.*
    from table1 ta
    cross apply(select tb.name from tableb tb where tb.aid=ta.bid1) a1
    cross apply(select tb.name from tableb tb where tb.aid=ta.bid2) a2
```